# Linear factors of non homogeneous PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Is there a general rule for finding linear factor of auxiliary equation of non homogeneous partial differential equation with constant coefficients like algebraic equation.

Find Linear factors of each of the following questions.

Question 1

$(D^2 - DD' + D' - 1)z =0$

Question 2

$(D^2 - D'^2 + D + 3D' - 2)z = 0$

Question 3

$(D^2 + DD' - 6D'^2)z = 0$

Question 4

$(D^2 - D'^2 + D - D')z = 0$

My Attempt:

Auxiliary equation of question 4 is

$D^2 - D'^2 + D - D' = 0$ or $(D - D')(D + D') + (D - D') = 0$ or
$(D - D')(D + D' + 1) = 0$
So linear factors of
$D^2 - D'^2 + D - D' $
are given by

$(D - D')(D + D' + 1) $

Comment: Anyone can help me

Comment: Here $D$ means   $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ and $D'$ means $\frac{\partial }{\partial y}$

Comment: Similarly $D^2$ means second partial derivative with respect to x and $D'^2$ means second partial derivative with respect to y

Answer (score 1):

Generally the factorization can be done by inspection.

If you cannot find it that simple way, write down the expected form. For example in case (2) :
$$D^2-D'^2+D+3D'-2=(D+aD'+b)(D+cD'+d)$$
$a,b,c,d$ are constants to be determined.

$$(ac+1)D'^2+(a+c)DD'+(b+d-1)D+(ad+bc-3)D'+(bd+2)=0$$
$$\begin{cases}
ac+1=0\\
a+c=0\\
b+d-1=0\\
ad+bc-3=0\\
bd+2=0
\end{cases}$$
Solving the system for the unknown $a,b,c,d$ leads to two solutions:
$$\begin{cases}
a=1 \\
b=-1 \\
c=-1 \\
d=2
\end{cases} \quad\text{and}\quad
\begin{cases}
a=-1 \\
b=2 \\
c=1 \\
d=-1
\end{cases}$$
The both solutions are equivalent :
$$(D+D'-1)(D-D'+2)z=0\quad\text{and}\quad (D-D'+2)(D+D'-1)z=0$$